# How does Django choose template name for CreateView when I don’t specify it

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

How does the CreatePostView in views.py link to the post_form.html.

It does not have "template_name" in it still how does the createpostview links to the post_form.html?

Please look into the following codes that i have added below, and let me know if you can help, Thankyou!

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post, Comment
from .forms import PostForm, CommentForm

from django.views.generic import (TemplateView,ListView,
                                  DetailView,CreateView,
                                  UpdateView,DeleteView)

from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class CreatePostView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'

    form_class = PostForm

    model = Post
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('post/new/', views.CreatePostView.as_view(), name='post_new'),
]
```

post_form.html

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>New post</h1>

    <form method="POST" class="post-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>

    <script>var editor = new MediumEditor('.editable');</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Please help me understand this.

Answer (score 1):

For a model `Post` in app `myapp`, the `CreateView` will use the template `myapp/post_form.html`.

This is just the [documented behaviour](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView.template_name_suffix) of `CreateView`.

You might find it useful to look at the [`get_template_names`](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.1/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/#get_template_names) method on the ccbv website to understand how the code works.